# Draft-js do not save database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, draftjs

I am unable to save `description` as part of the component's state. I can only save the title. How do I save title and description to the database?

```
const BlogCreate = ({ history }) => {
const [blogCreate, setBlogCreate] = useState({
    title: "",
    description: ""
});
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    EditorState.createEmpty(),
);
const handleChange = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const { name, value } = currentTarget;
    setBlogCreate({...blogCreate, [name]: value});
};
const onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
    setEditorState(editorState);
};
const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())); 
    try {
        await blogAPI.create(blogCreate, data);
    } catch (error) {
         console.log(error)
        }
    }
    console.log(data);
}
return(
      <Field type="text" name="title" error={errors.title} value={blogCreate.title} 
               onChange={handleChange} 
             />
      <Editor name="description" editorState={editorState} onEditorStateChange={editorState => onEditorStateChange(editorState)}
             />
      <button type="submit">Save</button>    
   );
}
export default BlogCreate;
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the issue you are facing? There are more than 1 headers being saved..?

Comment: Yes, I have two fields with a title and description.
Write to the database is only the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the full code you've provided me, I realised that you aren't properly updating the `blogCreate` state whenever there is a change at the `Editor` component.

The `onEditorStateChange()` should be updating the `blogCreate` state, and in addition, `changeValue()` needs to return the result `value`.

```
const changeValue = editorState => {
  const value = ....

  return value;
};

const onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
  const description = changeValue(editorState);
  setBlogCreate({
     ...blogCreate,
     description,
  });
  setEditorState(editorState);
};
```

This way, `description` will be properly updated on your state, and it will be sent to your server side when you make the `blogAPI.create()` request.